# How do you get file assets off the server in twig?

Tags: theming

I have a small part of a website that relies on a bunch of csv files. When I built the site I just used the following code to grab the csv files, however I am now getting 404 not found errors.

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: './data/mapping.csv',
      success: function success(res) {
        var y = $.csv.toObjects(res);
        data = data.concat(y);
      },
      error: function error(e) {
        return console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

I placed all the csv files into a file named data and placed that file into a library folder under the theme. I then used the `{{ directory }}` string in place of the ./ to yeild this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: './{{ base_path ~ directory }}/library/data/mapping.csv',
      success: function success(res) {
        var y = $.csv.toObjects(res);
        data = data.concat(y);
      },
      error: function error(e) {
        return console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

Is there something else I need to include or another way this would be achieved in drupal?

Comment: Why are you using ./ in URls? URLs aren't filenames. Are you sure the server is not set to block any access to those files?

Comment: Also shoving JS scripts directly into Twigs is not a good approach and certainly not the way you should work in Drupal with JS and templating. Try using a library in your theme or module and put the code inside a behavior https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: Additionally core is moving out of jQuery, means that core JS won't depend on jQuery (I think this is nearly complete if not already) and neither you should rely on it for your modules or themes. Check this post on how to move away from jQuery https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/removing-jquery-from-your-drupal-theme